# Async background multi-file upload?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload, asyncfileupload, multifile-uploader

I'm creating an asp.net web app. I want to allow the user to upload one or more huge files for import (preferably via a drag/drop interface, if possible.) After the upload is initiated I would like for the user to be able to navigate the website as desired. When the file(s) upload is complete I would like a pop up message to appear, wherever they are on the website, telling the user that the upload is complete. Is this possible? (I'm thinking that the user will not be able to leave the page.) Any 3rd party controls, etc.... that would help me out here? Thanks for your insight!

Comment: If you want them to navigate around without leaving the page, well that's the definition of a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Comment: I was wondering if they could start upload then navigate to other pages of the site while the files uploaded.

Comment: That's my point: if you build a SPA, they can navigate to other pages within the site without entirely reloading the current page.

Comment: Interesting @mason. Thanks for your input. I will research SPA further and see if this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Am pretty sure you should be able to do this with [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com).

Another option I have used in the past is the [RadAsyncUpload](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) component from Telerik, but this is paid software.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the Telerik control before. I'll check out dropzone too. That does help me out with part of the problem. Just wondering though, can I start the upload, then navigate to another page in the website and be notified with the upload(s) are done?